# Can i get data from previous Windows build back?

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, windows-update

I have installed Windows update and all of the events in Event Viewer are gone. Can i get them back even thought i updated Windows more than a month ago? Also, haven’t done backup.

Comment: I assume the update you are talking about is a feature update?

Comment: Let alone the fact that a windows 10 feature update will basically reinstall windows, and as such also the core components such as the eventlog are refreshed, The event log itself is not permanent either. At some point, old events will be deleted otherwise the eventlog would become so big, you'd lose too much diskspace.

Comment: @bandjet - " Also my registry files are gone prior to that update." - What files exactly? If you installed a feature update, your registry absolutely, should not have been wiped.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i get them back even thought i updated Windows more than a month
> ago   ....    Also, haven’t done backup.

It is not at all likely that you can retrieve the old events. You cannot (normally) roll back Windows after more than a month.

You can try restoring to a prior point, but that is not likely to succeed (too much time gone by).

So you are out of luck on this one, so far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say with certainty.  You say you ran a Windows Update, was that just a simple update?  Or did you update to a new Windows build?  Either way Windows would not clear the Event logs.  This is typically done manually by an administrator.  Its strange that the log was cleared.

As for recovering, you can try to do a System Restore.  If the data from the previous version of Windows is still there, it might be able to go back to a previous point in time.

You can also try to recover the logs with data restoration software.  By default, they are in `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`.  However, if its been over a month, the likelihood of recovery is very low.

Comment: @Ramhound just meant update.  fixed.